# R programming - replace first and the second string in parenthesis

Tags: r

E.g:

I have the following variable:

```
fileNamewithParams <- "myfunction(firstVariable,secondVariable)"
```

The variable will change however the pattern remains the same.
that is a string with two parameters.

firstVarToChange <- 'newFirstVariable'

secondVarToChange <- 'newSecondVariable'

I want to replace `firstVariable` and `secondVariable` with firstVarToChange and secondVarToChange .

The values in the parenthesis will change however the values to replace with is always constant in this case firstVarToChange and secondVarToChange.

Need to create a program such that the regular expression will recognize 
the first value and the second value in parenthesis respectively
such that i get

```
fileNamewithParams <- "myfunction(newFirstVariable,newSecondVariable)"
```

Your help will be immensely appreciated.

Comment: Do you really have R code stored in strings? That seems very odd. What are you **really** trying to do? It seems like you may have started down a bad path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know R but I'm pretty good with regexes.  I'll give you some ideas and maybe that will do it.

```
myfunction\(([^,]+),([^)]+)
```

There are 2 capture groups, one for each inside the parans.  What this regex is doing is using a character class to match from the right of the first paran and at least 1 non comma, up to a comma, and then up to the left of the next paran.

So to use that, your next line is going to be the 2 capture groups. $1 and $2, or something, I'm not sure what they are in R.  Hopefully that is enough to point you in the right direction.  :)

Answer (score 0):

First match 'myfunction' and use the '(' and ',' and ')' as delimiters. 
something like:

Search:

```
myfunction\(.*,.*\)
```

replace

```
myfunction(newFirstVariable,newSecondVariable)
```